# Get the current user Liferay using a simple Java code

Tags: authentication, jboss, struts2, liferay, portal

I'm working with : **Liferay 6.0.6** with **JBoss 5.1** and **Struts2**.

My question is, how to get the current user in **Liferay** once logged in, using a **Java** code.

Comment: I meant, the solution should be a Java Code and we have to retrieve the current user by E-mail :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your doView/processAction method do following

```
User user = (User) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);
```

or use the ThemeDisplay object. It contains another information like companyId, groupId, ...

```
ThemeDisplay td  =(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
User user = td.getUser();
```

Classes ThemeDisplay, User nad WebKeys are part of portal-service.jar.

If you need just some id to identify current user you can also use

```
String userId = request.getRemoteUser();
```

This solution is not Liferay specific and should be portable among jsr-286 portals.

Comment: can you tell me more about the instance "request". how to initialize it ?

Comment: Its either RenderRequest, ActionRequest, EventRequest or ResourceRequest. If you are not familiar with them then you should read some portlet tutorial, e.g http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/understanding-the-two-phases-of-portlet-execution

Comment: User currentUser = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance().getUser();

Answer (score 6):

Liferay provides Util class

> com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil

This class contains all utility methods to get the frequently used attributes.

Try using `PortalUtil.getUser(PortletRequest portletRequest)` method to avoid creating new objects and references.

Comment: What's is the different with ThemeDisplay?

Comment: @zhelon, nothing, you fetch themeDisplay from request, and then getUser() from it, PortalUtil.getUser() fetches the same from request, if you see PortalImpl.getUser() then you will notice this request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);

Answer (score 6):

This is an other possible way to do it  :

```
private LiferayFacesContext liferayFacesContext = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance();
User currentUser=liferayFacesContext.getUser()
```