# How can I get the current user in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay-6

How can I get the current user connected to a Liferay portal with a simple *Java* code?

I'm using **Liferay 6.0.6**

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448193/get-the-current-user-liferay-using-a-simple-java-code

Comment: This is possible duplicate of the issue mentioned by @dragon66. This might also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970986/accessing-the-user-from-a-liferay-portlet

Answer (score 28):

Simply:

```
User currentUser = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
```

Answer (score 10):

In your doView/processAction method do following

```
User user = (User) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);
```

or use the ThemeDisplay object. It contains another information like companyId, groupId, ...

```
ThemeDisplay td  =(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
User user = td.getUser();
```

Classes ThemeDisplay, User and WebKeys are part of portal-service.jar.

If you need just some id to identify current user you can also use

```
String userId = request.getRemoteUser();
```

This solution is not Liferay specific and should be portable among jsr-286 portals.

Source: [Get the current user Liferay using a simple Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448193/get-the-current-user-liferay-using-a-simple-java-code)

Answer (score 3):

In Java Code:

- `UserLocalServiceUtil.getXXX` methods are there, choose as you want.

In JSP Code:

- `themeDisplay.getUserId()` will give you the current user id
- `themeDisplay.getUser()` will give you the object of current User.