# Liferay - Get User Groups for a user

Tags: liferay-6

I need to get the list of User Groups for a given user. 
That user should can either be the current logged in user or any other user in Liferay.
What is the Liferay API Call that I need to use?

Is using `UserGroupLocalServiceUtil` the only way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways which can retrieve the User Group List.

1. Retrieve the User object first and call the `getUserGroups()` on the User Object as shown below

   `List<UserGroup> userGroupList = user.getUserGroups();`
2. Use the `UserGroupLocalServiceUtil` class to retrieve the User Group List.

   `List<UserGroup> userGroupList = UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserUserGroups(user.getUserId());`

There are many other useful methods that can be utilized.

- To paginate the retrieved User Group List through these methods:

  `List<UserGroup> userGroupList = UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserUserGroups(userId, start, end);`
- To paginate and sort the User Group List

  `List<UserGroup> userGroupList = UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserUserGroups(userId, start, end, orderByComparator)`
- To get the number of User Groups for a User

  `int userGroupCount = UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserUserGroupsCount(userId);`

To get the User object, you can use any of the following API calls.

```
User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserById(userId);
User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyId, screenName);
User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(companyId, emailAddress);
```

The companyId in the above calls can be retrieved using:

`long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request);`

To get the current logged in user, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10555521/668240