# How to get Uuid from User

Tags: java, liferay

I am trying to get the UUID from a user.

So far i tried

[Accessing the user from a liferay portlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970986/accessing-the-user-from-a-liferay-portlet)

[Get the current user Liferay using a simple Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448193/get-the-current-user-liferay-using-a-simple-java-code)

putting `String userId = renderRequest.getRemoteUser()` into the view.jsp worked to get the intern ID.

However i wanted the UUID instead.

If i use the code from the links above (into the java-class doView) i only get a null-user object.

Using getUserUuid() and getUuid() returns null.

Here is my class:

```
    ThemeDisplay td  =(ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    User user = td.getUser();
    String userId = user.getUuid();
    renderRequest.setAttribute("myUser", userId);
```

and my view.jsp

```
<%
String userId = (String) renderRequest.getAttribute("myUser");
%>
<%= userId %>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On JSP, extract your parameter from implicit request object. Like:

```
<%
String userId = (String) request.getAttribute("myUser");
%>
```

Comment: this worked. i did not use `request` because it could not be resolved into a variable before. Now it just works fine. thanks